# Unable to locate element in Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am trying to find an element which is like a container. I have used css selector and xpath. but I am getting unable to locate element. Could someone help?

Here is the full html snippet

```
<div class="container" data-aura-rendered-by="44:87;a"><header data-aura-rendered-by="45:87;a">
                Klant zoeken
                <a href="https://website/image/path/" data-aura-rendered-by="47:87;a"><span class="icon icon-sluiten" data-aura-rendered-by="48:87;a"></span></a></header><section class="wrapper" data-aura-rendered-by="49:87;a"><div class="logo" data-aura-rendered-by="50:87;a"></div><div class="span12 container_12" data-aura-rendered-by="51:87;a"><div class="interactions siteDesignTimeRegion" data-region-name="content" data-allow-drop="true" data-item-id="6365fc9c-51b9-1255" data-aura-rendered-by="6:87;a" data-aura-class="siteDesignTimeRegion"><div class="emptyRegionPlaceholder siteEmptyRegion" data-aura-rendered-by="10:87;a" data-aura-class="siteDesignTimeEmptyRegion">Add components (content)
    </div><!--render facet: 18:87;a--></div></div></section></div>
```

Actual container is below

```
<div class="interactions siteDesignTimeRegion" data-region-name="content" data-allow-drop="true" data-item-id="6365fc9c-51b9-1255" data-aura-rendered-by="6:87;a" data-aura-class="siteDesignTimeRegion">
```

CSS lookup: div.container div.interactions.siteDesignTimeRegion

XPath: /html/body/div[4]/div[4]/body/div[2]/section/div[2]/div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css or xpath.

For css use:

```
div.interactions.siteDesignTimeRegion
```

For xpath use:

```
//div[@class='interactions siteDesignTimeRegion']
```

Always try to select an element by attributes when possible and avoid using absolute xpaths like the one you gave as example.

Comment: thanks..my css lookup and xpath are also correct. But element is located in iframe. It works when I switch to frame and then find the element